# how to set name of backup directory generated by Percona xtrabackup?

Tags: mysql, database-backups, percona

I have installed percona-xtrabackup-24.2.4.4 to take full backups of MySql db. i run following command to take backup

```
innobackupex --user=user_name --password=pass dir_path
```

it created a directory with timestamp( **e.g. 2016-09-26_12-36**) of mySql db successfully, which contains complete DB backup.

**The problem is, i want to specify the output directory name, which is by default created with timestamp.**

Any ideas? i have read all the options [percona](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/xtrabackup_bin/xbk_option_reference.html) mentioned but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood clearly I would suggest that you need smth like

```
innobackupex --user=yourDBuser --password=MaGiCdB1 --no-timestamp /path/to/backupdir
```

where

**--no-timestamp** key tells not to create a time stamped directory to store the backup

**/path/to/backupdi**r - path to your backup file

You can find information about **--no-timestamp** option here

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/innobackupex/creating_a_backup_ibk.html

Answer (score 1):

Bilal, with newer releases of Percona Xtrabackup you do not need to use the innobackupex script. The xtrabackup binary can create your backup for you. Using the following notation, you can create your backup with a custom output dir;

```
[moore@randy backup]$ pwd
/data/backup

[moore@randy backup]$ sudo xtrabackup --user=root \
--password=*** \
--backup \
--target-dir=./full_backup
160927 13:15:51 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: root, password: set, port: 0, socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Using server version 5.7.14-7-log
xtrabackup version 2.4.4 based on MySQL server 5.7.13 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: df58cf2)
xtrabackup: uses posix_fadvise().
xtrabackup: cd to /var/lib/mysql
xtrabackup: open files limit requested 0, set to 1024
xtrabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_home_dir = .
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_file_size = 50331648
...
160927 13:15:54 Finished backing up non-InnoDB tables and files
160927 13:15:54 Executing FLUSH NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG ENGINE LOGS...
xtrabackup: The latest check point (for incremental): '2500658'
xtrabackup: Stopping log copying thread.
.160927 13:15:54 >> log scanned up to (2500667)

160927 13:15:54 Executing UNLOCK TABLES
160927 13:15:54 All tables unlocked
160927 13:15:54 [00] Copying ib_buffer_pool to /data/backup/full_backup/ib_buffer_pool
160927 13:15:54 [00]        ...done
160927 13:15:54 Backup created in directory '/data/backup/full_backup'
160927 13:15:54 [00] Writing backup-my.cnf
160927 13:15:54 [00]        ...done
160927 13:15:54 [00] Writing xtrabackup_info
160927 13:15:54 [00]        ...done
xtrabackup: Transaction log of lsn (2500642) to (2500667) was copied.
160927 13:15:55 completed OK!

[moore@randy backup]$ ls -l
drwxr-x---. 7 root root 4096 Sep 27 13:15 full_backup

[moore@randy backup]$ sudo ls -l ./full_backup/
total 12336
-rw-r-----. 1 root root      425 Sep 27 13:15 backup-my.cnf
-rw-r-----. 1 root root      304 Sep 27 13:15 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 12582912 Sep 27 13:15 ibdata1
drwxr-x---. 2 root root     4096 Sep 27 13:15 mysql
drwxr-x---. 2 root root     8192 Sep 27 13:15 performance_schema
drwxr-x---. 2 root root     8192 Sep 27 13:15 sys
drwxr-x---. 2 root root       19 Sep 27 13:15 sysbench
drwxr-x---. 2 root root       19 Sep 27 13:15 t1
-rw-r-----. 1 root root      113 Sep 27 13:15 xtrabackup_checkpoints
-rw-r-----. 1 root root      448 Sep 27 13:15 xtrabackup_info
-rw-r-----. 1 root root     2560 Sep 27 13:15 xtrabackup_logfile
```

Comment: yeah it works, i have tried this command, 

xtrabackup --user=user --password=pass --backup --target-dir=path_with_formated_dir_name

Thanks for your views

but was trying to work with innobackupex